# Why is across slower than summarize_all in dplyr 1.0.0?

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize, across

I just updated to the latest `dplyr` version 1.0.0. Trying out the new features in the `summarize` function, like `across` and `.groups`. But to my surprise, my code has become very slow compared to the former version. Is this a known issue? Am I doing anything wrong?? Check out the example.

```
# Create example data set
library(tidyverse)
n_grps <- 10000
n_rep <- 1000
tbbl <- tibble(grp = rep(1:n_grps, each = n_rep),
               value1 = rnorm(n_grps * n_rep),
               value2 = rnorm(n_grps * n_rep))
```

Running this the old fashioned way

```
library(tictoc)
tic()
tbbl %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  summarize_all(mean) %>% 
  ungroup()
toc()
```

takes less than a second on my Windows machine. Replacing it by `summarize` / `across`

```
tic()
tbbl %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  summarize(across(everything(), mean), .groups = "drop")
toc()
```

takes more than 9 seconds!

Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I think it's a known issue: [across() performance slow compared to scoped variant](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/4953).